# Is there any .editorconfig GUI editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, editorconfig

EditorConfig is amazing tool, and I'm excited that in vs2017 developers can use it out of the box. But there are too many settings which should be set for each project. Visual Studio and ReSharper have awesome syntax code style editor, with GUI and live preview. But I haven't found same tool for EditorConfig. Otherwise it would be great if anybody knows way to export ReSharper or VS setting in .editorconfig format. I mean full settings with csharp specific. Actually, all settings specified [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference.md)

Answer (score 9):

Mads Kristensen has written an extension that allows you to add editorconfig file and it comes complete with intellisense for VS2017 - "EditorConfig Language Service"

Check it out [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.EditorConfig) or download from VS2017.  No UI, but you don't need a UI with this.  Not a bad starter for ten...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 16.10 added a UI for editing editorconfig files.